# How to dowload folders from a Documents Library using code?

Tags: javascript, document-library, folder, file, download

Here's the thing: I need to add a button in the page that users can use to download a whole library to their computers.. BUT they must not be able to edit these folders! So I cannot make the button open the documents in a Explorer Window because they may erase or cut any file or folder by mistake, so I just need to add a button in the page which allows the users to download a copy of these folders in their computers, any idea how? (any javascript or html solution?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharepoint on premise,

You can implement "Download as Zip" Custom Action into your ribbon.
You can refer to this link as a sample http://adicodes.com/download-files-as-zip-file-in-sharepoint

Comment: So I guess there's no way to achieve this without implementing something in the ribbon, the thing is that as an employee in a corporate environment I'm not able to implement anything, but thanks anyway!!